# EntityFramework 6 - Disable DbUpdateConcurrency check

Tags: entity-framework, concurrency, triggers, insert, entity-framework-6

Is there any way to turn off Entity Framework concurrency checks for a specific statement or DbContext?

I can see EF generates a select straight after an Insert. E.g.

```
-- Insert Statement
INSERT X (a, b, c)
VALUE (m, n, o)

-- Concurrency Check
SELECT ID
FROM X
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND ID = scope_identity()
```

The reason I need to turn it off is because I am working with a table which has an Insert trigger which replaces the insert, does some logic, and then inserts it internally. Ane because of that the scope_identity() gets lost as the scope is `BEGIN`s and `END`s within the Trigger.

Unfortunately I cannot change the trigger :-( as it is out of my control :-( The trigger is there to ensure any combination of specific fields is not duplicated within the table so owners will not remove it.

Is there a way to tell EF to completely omit the *Concurrency Check* or tell it to use `@@IDENTITY`?